# Filter in DataGrid WPF is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, filtering

I have a filter functionality in place for my application which uses checkboxes to filter out certain observable collection items bound to a datagrid.  I do not get an error at all, the filter just does not function like I want it to.  Here's the xaml code for it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="jobItemViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:JobItem, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!--
 Irrelevant Content
  -->

<CheckBox Content="Show Active Jobs" Name="actJobsCheckBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="AddAFiltering" Unchecked="RemoveAFiltering" />
                <CheckBox Content="Show Completed Jobs" Name="compJobsCheckBox" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="AddCFiltering" Unchecked="RemoveCFiltering"/>

                <DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" LoadingRow="jobItemDataGrid_LoadingRow" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="jobItemDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="workOrderNoColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=WorkOrderNo}" Header="Work Order No." Width="75" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="assigneeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PrimaryAssignee}" Header="Assignee" Width="80" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dateReceivedColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=DateReceived}" Header="Date Received" Width="90" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dueDateColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=DueDate}" Header="Due Date" Width="90" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="statusColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status" Width="70" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                </DataGrid>
```

Then here is what I've written for the code behind:

```
public AdminView(Employee currEmployee)
    {
        this.Title = "Administrator View - " + currEmployee.Name;
        InitializeComponent();
        jobItemDataGrid.DataContext = JobItemList;
        jobItemViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["jobItemViewSource"]);

        LoadDummies();


    }

private void AddAFiltering(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        jobItemViewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ActiveJobs_Filter);
    }

    private void RemoveAFiltering(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        jobItemViewSource.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(ActiveJobs_Filter);
    }

    private void AddCFiltering(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        jobItemViewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(CompletedJobs_Filter);
    }

    private void RemoveCFiltering(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        jobItemViewSource.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(CompletedJobs_Filter);
    }

    private void ActiveJobs_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        JobItem currJob = e.Item as JobItem;
        if (currJob != null)
        {
            if (!currJob.Status.Equals("Completed"))
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CompletedJobs_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        JobItem currJob = e.Item as JobItem;
        if (currJob != null)
        {
            if (currJob.Status.Equals("Completed"))
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to fix it using your approach. But here is how I would accomplish this task. Make a property called FilteredJobItemList to bind to instead of the main list. Bind your checkboxes to properties IsActiveChecked/IsCompletedChecked. In the setters for these, raise the propertychanged event for your FilteredJobItemList.

```
public ObservableCollection<JobItem> FilteredJobItemList
{
   get
   {
      if ((IsActiveChecked) && (!IsCompletedChecked))
      {
          return JobItemList.Where(x => x.status != "Completed");
      }
      else if ((!IsActiveChecked) && (IsCompletedChecked))
      {
          return JobItemList.Where(x => x.status == "Completed");
      }
      else
      {
          return JobItemList;
      }
   }
}

public bool IsActiveChecked
{
   get
   {
      return _isActiveChecked;
   }
   set
   {
      if (value != _isActiveChecked)
      {
          _isActiveChecked = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("IsActiveChecked");
          OnPropertyChanged("FilteredJobItemList");
      }
   }
} 

public bool IsCompletedChecked
{
   get
   {
      return _isCompletedChecked;
   }
   set
   {
      if (value != _isCompletedChecked)
      {
          _isCompletedChecked = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("IsCompletedChecked");
          OnPropertyChanged("FilteredJobItemList");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I used this adding: actJobsCheckBox.DataContext = IsActiveChecked; compJobsCheckBox.DataContext = IsCompletedChecked;

and in xaml:

<CheckBox Content="Show Active Jobs" Name="actJobsCheckBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsActiveChecked}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Show Completed Jobs" Name="compJobsCheckBox" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCompletedChecked}/>

Comment: Hmmm...that should work. I'll have to look into it this evening after work. In the meantime, I suggest you look into MVVM architecture (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). My datacontext would be set for the entire view to my viewmodel. Then I would set the ItemsSource for the datagrid to be my FilteredJobItemList.

Comment: Did you change jobItemDataGrid.DataContext = JobItemList; to reference the FilteredJobItemList instead?

Comment: I actually forgot to set the itemssource for the datagrid to be FilteredJobItemList and when I changed it, now there aren't any items showing at all.

Comment: You are still populating your JobItemList, right? Put a breakpoint in the getter for the FilteredJobItemList and make sure that JobItemList has data.